# Deleting 'infinite' recursive directory

Tags: cyanogenmod, storage, shell, file-management, bugs

I created a new folder inside /sdcard/ and something went wrong with it since  other 600 sub-folders (one inside the other) were created as well. 
I noticed the problem when trying to rename the 'main' folder, as it returned a  "folder not found" error.

I know the number of sub-folders because I checked the properties of the main folders. There are also 160 files which I did not place there and I haven't checked what they are.

My phone is rooted and for the operation I used the CM built-in file manager. 
I've been trying deleting the folders both via UI and through the shell but nothing works. If I run

```
rm -r /sdcard/<myfolder>/
```

It returns "folder not empty". 
I've also tried the

```
-rf
```

option but nothing changes. 
Rebooting didn't solve the issue.

I hope it's not about a corrupted partition...

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you tried `-f` and `-r` separately. You need to use both the switches together, ie `rm -rf /sdcard/<yourfolder>/`

Comment: @daltofury42 No, I tried -rf, I've just edited my post to make that clear.

Comment: Try adding a `-v` switch and post back any relevant outputs.

Comment: Can you give us the output of `ls -l` on `/sdcard` and grep that folder in it? Also, do you have a custom Recovery installed? In my case, my `clockworkmod` directory wasn't getting deleted because I suppose it's group and owner wasn't `media_rw` and gave me the error `folder not empty`. I booted into custom Recovery and nuked it for good.

Comment: @daltofury42 No relevant outputs. @Firelord: `drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-09-09 11:00 Tasks`. Also yes, I've got TWRP installed. I think I'll try deleting the folders from there.

Comment: Successfully removed through the Recovery command line. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved by running `rm -r` from the Custom Recovery cmd.

I'll create the folder again and see if the problem reoccurs, hopefully it was just a 'random' glitch. 
(I should probably mention that I use a nightly version of CM12.1, not a stable ROM).